# Getting a “You have entered too many arguments for this function” in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to use the `INDEX` and `MATCH` function thus:

```
=INDEX(G2,I2,K2,S2:T2,Y2:AB2,0,MATCH(MAX(G3,I3,K3,S3:T3,Y3:AB3),G3,I3,K3,S3:T3,Y3:AB3,0))
```

Then I got the error message: `You have entered too many arguments for this function`

Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: `INDEX()` takes up to 4 arguments - you have given it 7. `MATCH() takes up to 3 arguments - you have given it 7. It is impossible to work out what you are trying to achieve, so I cannot suggest a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is wrong, because it has indeed to many arguments.

---

The `INDEX` function works like this:

```
=INDEX(<area where you're searching something>, <row number>, [<column number>])
```

Therefore:

- The 1st argument must be a range, for instance `G5:L10`.
- The 2nd argument must be the row number that you want to return in the range. With the range `G5:L10` and the argument `2`, you will return the 2nd row of that range, i.e. `6:6`.
- The 3rd argument is the same as the 2nd, but refers to the column number. It is optional.

Check [Excel's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD) for more information.

---

The `MATCH` function is used here because we don't really know which line/column number to use in the `INDEX`. However, tables often have a header with a human-readable name, or a first cell containing an ID, a date, a name, etc. It would be great to ask Excel: *"give me the number of the row that has the date 2018-05-24 inside"*, instead of *"use row number 634"*.

Luckily, the function `MATCH(<what>,<where>,<how>)` can do that. It simply returns the position of **what** you're searching, within the array of values (**where**). The **how** lets you configure how the function behaves (cf. [Excel's documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A)).

In other words, if your range contains:

```
1  Apple
2  Pear
3  Banana
4  Orange
```

The formula `MATCH("Banana", A1:A4, 0)` will return `2`.

---

By combining `INDEX` and `MATCH`, you can ask Excel to give you the intersection of a row and a column, within a given area of possible values.

I suggest you to consult this article about how to use INDEX`and`MATCH`:

> [Excel formula: Two-way lookup with INDEX and MATCH](https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match) on ExcelJet

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find the value in the cell above the cell that has the maximum value in a set of discontinuous ranges in the same row.

The actual solution to that, given your set of ranges, is:

```dart
=INDEX(2:2,MATCH(MAX(G3,I3,K3,S3:T3,Y3:AB3),3:3,0))
```